# How to allow Anyone to test my faceBot (facebook messenger bot)

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

How can I allow people to test my faceBot (facebook messenger bot)

Until there .. I should in every time adding tester and/or developer to test my chatBot 
and I should say it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're ready to make your bot live to the public, you need to submit it for approval by adding the messenger platform and submitting all the required items for approval to go public.
All the information you need on that can be found here [Messenger Bot Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review)

Comment: Thank you very match Bernard Parah  ... 
In fact it was visible but I did not notice it :D ... 
My application is under approval